# How to get the npm global path prefix

Tags: node.js, npm

I believe that  in the past I've discovered an option to pass to `npm` to get it to output the path it is using for `-g` (global modules). Does anyone know such an option? Or any other method to get the global path prefix `npm` is using?

I know where where the global modules live on my computer (`/usr/local/share/npm/bin`), and generally it only takes a few minutes to find global modules on other computers: usually `$PATH` is correctly configured, and if not, well, poking around does the trick. But isn't there be some quick way to tell how `npm` was built, and which path it's using for globals modules?

Answer (score 141, accepted):

`npm config get prefix` will return the path.

Answer (score 24):

How about `npm -g bin`?

It can be used with `export PATH="$(npm -g bin):$PATH"`. It will find npm's *bin* global directory (or if exist: local).

Comment: This should be `npm bin -g`, `npm bin` returns the location of where the local bin would be but doesn't appear to check for its existence.  `npm bin` alone never appears to return the global npm bin.