# node: Cannot find module (node installed with brew)

Tags: node.js, macos, bash, npm, homebrew

I try to run a script that i wrote in node. In order to debug and show you my problem, i reduced the script to:

```
#! /usr/bin/env node

var prompt = require('prompt');
```

When i try to run the script i get

```
module.js:340
  throw err;
        ^
Error: Cannot find module 'prompt'
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
  at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
  at require (module.js:380:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/derzyklop/S/dotfiles/bin/bugs:3:14)
  at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
  at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
  at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
```

I tried to install "prompt" with `npm install prompt` and also global with `npm install prompt -g`. But my script still doesn't work.

"prompt" seems to be installed, because `npm list --depth=0` gives me

[image: npm list]

and `npm list -g --depth=0` gives me

[image: npm list -g]

I installed node via brew, so the next thing i tried was that i removed node by `brew remove npm` and `brew remove node` and i downloaded the installer for OSX from [here](http://nodejs.org/download/). But that didn't change anything.

I'm out of ideas. Why can't node find the module? 
Is it possible, that `npm list -g` searches at other paths than the `require(..)` in my script?

---

### Update

The script is located in my personal bin-folder in **~/dotfiles/bin/myscript** which is added to $PATH by `export PATH=~/dotfiles/bin:$PATH`.

I found out, that require() searches global modules in **{prefix}/lib/node_modules**, where **{prefix}** is [`npm config get prefix`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18383476/how-to-get-the-npm-global-path-prefix).

So i can temporary fix it by doing this: `require('/usr/local/lib/node_modules/prompt');`.

Local modules are searched in **./node_modules**. In my case this must be **~/dotfiles/bin/node_modules**, so i did

```
cd ~/dotfiles/bin/
npm install prompt
```

and with this i can use `require('prompt');` in my script.

So the question is: How do i let my node-script search for modules in `{executing directory}/node_modules`?
And still: Why is `require()` not searching in `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/`?