# How do i let my node-script search for modules in `{executing directory}/node_modules`?

Tags: node.js, bash, shell, npm

[Long story](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25773828/node-cannot-find-module-node-installed-with-brew) short:

I have a script in my personal bin-folder in **~/dotfiles/bin/myscript** which is added to $PATH by `export PATH=~/dotfiles/bin:$PATH`.

The current content of **myscript** is

```
#! /usr/bin/env node

var prompt = require('prompt');
```

[prompt](https://www.npmjs.org/package/prompt) is installed globally and locally. But `require('prompt')` says it

```
Cannot find module 'prompt'
```

I found out, that require() usually searches modules in

- ./node_modules (local)
- {prefix}/lib/node_modules (global)

I found my {prefix} by [`npm config get prefix`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18383476/how-to-get-the-npm-global-path-prefix).

So i could install the package in `~/dotfiles/bin/node_modules` or use `require('/usr/local/lib/node_modules/prompt');` in my script. Both work, but are no solution to me.

So the question is: 
How do i let my node-script search for modules in `{executing directory}/node_modules`?
And why isn't `require()` searching in `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/` anyway?

Comment: did you find any solution? I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: @khagesh no. didn't find a solution. i wrote a shell-script instead of node-script now. but i would still prefer a node solution for this :/