# cross-platform programming technique to obtain the global npm prefix

Tags: node.js

I need to access the list of globally installed packages (those installed via `npm install -g`) so I need to obtain the global *prefix*.

I already know about `npm config get prefix` (see [How to get the npm global path prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18383476/how-to-get-the-npm-global-path-prefix)) But, how can I code it on my node.js program?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`child_process.exec()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) to run the command:

```
var child_process = require('child_process');
child_process.exec('npm config get prefix', function(err, stdout){
    var prefix = stdout.toString(); // stdout was a Buffer
    console.log(prefix);
});
```

Comment: yep, thanks, I was wondering if there exists a more native way.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use npm programatically, as such:

```
var npm = require('npm')
var prefix = npm.config.get('prefix');
```

More information here:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm
- https://docs.npmjs.com/api/config