# Error running shell script using bash and node.js

Tags: node.js, bash, shell

I get the following error (error.message) when I run the following shell script (myscript.sh).

myscript.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /path/to/ && node app.js
```

error.message

> /path/to/myscript.sh: line 1: #!/bin/bash: No such file or directory
>
> /path/to/myscript.sh: line 2: node: command not found

I have already run the following command line instructions.

command-line

```
chmod u+x /path/to/myscript.sh
chmod u+x /path/to/app.js
```

Also, I know I have node installed because when I run:

```
node -v
```

I get back:

```
v5.5.1
```

I execute `myscript.sh` via the following AppleScript:

MyApp.applescript

```
do shell script "bash /path/to/myscript.sh"
```

Also: `which bash` returns `/bin/bash`

What could be causing this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: what happens if you split `cd /path/to/ && node app.js` into 2 separate lines?

Comment: also , how are you executing `myscript.sh`?

Comment: @the_velour_fog: I get the same result. Same error message.

Comment: your not trying to `source myscript` are you ?, you should execute it

Comment: @the_velour_fog: I execute `myscript.sh` via the following AppleScript: `do shell script "bash /path/to/myscript.sh"`.  (See above.)

Comment: @the_velour_fog: What do you mean by "you should ***execute*** it?" How, specifically, do you recommend I do this? Is there a command line instruction you have in mind?

Comment: Have you confirmed that 'bash' is actually installed in /bin and not something else like, e.g., dash?

Comment: short answer. try removing the `#!bin/bash`

Comment: Most of the time "#!/bin/bash: No such file or directory", message indicates that the script file encoding or line endings are wrong. Which editor are you using?

Comment: @Kadir: I am using Sublime Text 2.

Comment: @nautical: How would I confirm that 'bash' is actually installed in /bin and not something else like, e.g., dash?

Comment: @the_velour_fog: When I remove `#!bin/bash` I get the following error: `/usr/bin/cd: line 4: builtin: cd: not a shell builtin`

Comment: @Mowzer Run 'which bash' to confirm the location of it.

Comment: @HeadCode: `which bash` returns `/bin/bash`

Comment: @Mowzer to check and change the line endings of the script you can use `View->Line Endings->Unix` from the menu.

Comment: I'm betting Kadir is right. You will also probably need to put in the full path to node.

Comment: @Kadir: I have the ***Unix*** option checked in my view > line endings menu. (Other options are ***Windows*** and ***Mac***). But I'm unclear what I should be looking for regarding ***line endings***. Could you please explain further or give an example?

Comment: @HeadCode: Do you mean change `node app.js` to `node /path/to/app.js`? If that *is* what you meant, I tried it already and it didn't help.

Comment: @Mowzer Unix/Linux and mac os x use LF (new line) but windows  CRLF (Carriage Return) to indicate the end of each line in text files. If it is set uncorrectly that can cause unusual behavior when executing it. It seems like you have correct line endings. The last thing i can say give a try to check your file encoding to be UTF-8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit goes to @HeadCode and @mh-cbon for helping me figure this out with their comments.

I solved the second problem by running:

myshell.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
path/to/node path/to/app.js
```

where path/to/node was found by running

command-line

```
which node
```

and path/to/app.js is the actual file tree path to app.js. (In other words, *different* from path/to/node.)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the first error:

> /path/to/myscript.sh: line 1: #!/bin/bash: No such file or directory

By copying a working `.sh` file I had on my machine and copy/pasting the code from the old file to the new file.

I'm guessing somehow there was a filetype issue or discrepancy despite the fact that I used a `.sh` extension in the file name.

In the future, I will double check the file type in my Finder utility (Max OS X v10.10.1).

However, I am still seeing the second error:

> /path/to/myscript.sh: line 2: node: command not found

Comment: Change line 2 to /path/to/node app.js

Comment: @HeadCode: Error: `No such file or directory`

Comment: You did change /path/to/node to the real path to node on your machine, right?

Comment: @HeadCode: Lol. Thanks for asking. Apparently, no, I did not. How would I find that?

Comment: @HeadCode: Oh wait. [I just read this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18383601/1640892). So I ran `npm config get prefix` and got back a bunch of stuff. Included among it was this: `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npmlog/node_modules/are-we-there-yet/index.js:2:14` So I wonder what does that tell me?

Comment: `which node` should give you path to node binary file.

Comment: @mh-cbon: Thanks. That worked! `which node` returned `/usr/local/bin/node`. Very clean. Very nice.

Comment: @HeadCode: FYI. Your suggestion worked. I found `/usr/local/bin/node` by running `which node`.