# How to use global dependencies in Fish shell?

Tags: fish

After installing a global dependency using:

```
npm install -g react-native-cli
```

Fish shell does not recognize the global command. After looking around on SO I found a few posts related to npm install bin being in the `$PATH`. I tried some of the suggestion but could not find a solution.

**echo $PATH**

```
/usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin /usr/local/bin /opt/X11/bin
```

How do I include my global node modules in my path? Or is there another solution?

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:bash]?

Comment: Quick googling gets me https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/3023

Comment: yes, I saw this article. With a solution 

(Just a note, what ended up fixing my issue was editing the config.fish file and setting:

set PATH /Users/{myusername}/{global-npm-folder}/bin $PATH)

I am just having trouble finding out how to actually do this.

Comment: Uh... You solved it but you don't know how?

Comment: I am a command line noob. I'm not sure where to find/how to edit config.fish, also how to find the name of the global-npm-folder

Comment: I meant to add a second duplicate but with the [tag:bash] tag gone I can't. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18383476/how-to-get-the-npm-global-path-prefix and if you have further questions, googling those won't be very hard either.

Comment: There has been some dissatisfaction with the search facilities on Stack Overflow itself. I usually google with `site:stackoverflow.com` as a search term (but often don't need to, because SO generally comes up among the top search results in Google for me even without that).